# Disassemble in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

How to print the variable address/value, which is causing a core dump in my function.

From gdb disassemble command, I am seeing the below frames.

```
0x00000000005f3ae5 <+8373>: movl   $0x404,(%rsp)
0x00000000005f3aec <+8380>: mov    $0xda56f5,%r9d
0x00000000005f3af2 <+8386>: mov    $0xda77f0,%r8d
0x00000000005f3af8 <+8392>: mov    $0xda6870,%ecx
0x00000000005f3afd <+8397>: jmpq   0x5f1c15 <RmsArchiveRestSession::buildAndSendArchMmsReq(bool)+485>
0x00000000005f3b02 <+8402>: callq  0x5daaa0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt> ==> cause of dump
```

Here, how can I print the variable value/address which caused to call the `_stack_chk_fail` function..?
I am very new to this ..? Please explain me some basic fundas.

```
=> 0x00000000005f3b07 <+8407>:  mov    %rax,%r15
   0x00000000005f3b0a <+8410>:  mov    %r13,%rdi
   0x00000000005f3b0d <+8413>:  callq  0x8514f0 <MavString::~MavString()>
```

Please someone help me to understand above snippet.

Comment: The code that branches to `<+8402>` is not shown.

Comment: i am very sorry to ask very basic non-sense questions Jester, plz bear with me.
What does it mean by <+8402>..?
Basically, my function "buildAndSendArchMmsReq" has more than 2k lines and all stmts are string operations.

Comment: Surely there is a branch to that address hidden in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Here, how can I print the variable value/address which caused to call the _stack_chk_fail

You can't: the snippet in your question is "too late". There is `jmp 0x5f3b0d` somewhere *else* in your function, and *that* is where the failure is detected.